# Data validation with multiple parameters

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make sure the user doesn't input anything except a positive integer. Minus numbers and letters are not allowed. I'm having trouble with setting those two parameters for my data validation. Code is below:

```
product = 0

while product < 100:
    number = input("Enter a positive integer: ")
    try:[
        number = int(number),
        number = number.isnumeric
        ]
        
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a positive integer.")
        continue
        
    product = number * 10
    print("The number entered is", number, " and the product is", product)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, the below program should work:

```py
product = 0

while product < 100:
    number = input("Enter a positive integer: ")
    try:
        number = int(number)
        if number <= 0:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a positive integer.")
            continue
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a positive integer.")
        continue

    product = number * 10
    print("The number entered is", number, "and the product is", product)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isdigit` function:

> Return True if the string is a digit string, False otherwise.
> A string is a digit string if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character in the string.

For example:

```
>>> "-1".isdigit()
False
>>> "1.1".isdigit()
False
>>> "123".isdigit()
True
>>> "abc".isdigit()
False
```

---

In your case, you can do the following:

```py
product = 0

while product < 100:
    num_in = input("Enter a positive integer: ")
    if num_in.isdigit():
        number = int(number)
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a positive integer.")
        continue
    
    product = number * 10
    print("The number entered is", number, " and the product is", product)
```

---

- Note: You can also use `try-except` but it will take more conditions as `int` can also be a negative number.